# How do I remove EOF in cin buffer?

Tags: c++, io, iostream, cin, eof

I'm using an example to show what I mean: On my Mac, to leave the first "while loop", the user has to type "CTRL+D". From what I understand, that is achieved by adding an EOF into the cin buffer, thus "c >> x" returns false. Now, I intend the user to enter the second "while loop" after leaving the first loop. How do I clear the EOF from the cin buffer, so that "cin >>" y returns true?

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    while(cin >> x)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    
    if(cin.get()==EOF) cout << "yes" << endl;
    while(cin >> y)
    {
        cout << y*y << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The input has ended.  There is no more input.

Comment: There's no `EOF` in the input buffer. The input stream has been set to an error state. You need to clear the state: `std::cin.clear()`. But the console might have its own ideas about what happens after `ctrl-D`.

Comment: @PeteBecker But why does (cin.get()==EOF) returns true?

Comment: Because `get()` returns `EOF` when the stream is in an error state: `if (stream-is-in-error) return EOF; else return-next-character;`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late to answer, but for others who might have a similar situation like mine; I have to handle `EOF` signal while prompting user and still need `stdin` later in the program. One way to go about it is to do fork/wait ([a general example](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/cpp-fork/)), so that the piece of code where `EOF` is expected can be executed by another child process and then terminate without effecting `stdin` of the parent process.

I've tried before other solutions without success i.e `std::cin.clear()`. The `stdin` of your program should be shutdown, if `EOF` is signaled -- usually via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (unix) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (windows).